# Python, map with lambda returns only None Objects on my list()

Tags: python, function, oop, lambda

I Have that code:

```
    class Welcome(object):
        MyHouse='Earth'
        def say(self, what):
            print(what, self.MyHouse)

    welcome = Welcome()

    Living = ['World', 'Planet', welcome.MyHouse]

    MyChoice = list(map(lambda choice : setattr(welcome, 'MyHouse', choice), Living))
    print(''.join(str(MyChoice) for MyChoice in MyChoice))
    getattr(welcome, 'say')('Hello')
```

with this code , I want to use setattr() to change the MyHouse variable according to the strings contained in the Living list, but when I see the results I only get None objects ?, why this and how can I fix it, it would be because setattr does not give output ?.

```
    print(MyChoice) 
    Output: [None, None, None]
```

Comment: What did you think `setattr` would return?

Comment: but the var is not changing

Answer (score 0):

so, after a coffee I managed to solve,
I just needed to use a for loop
although I do not know the exact reason why this worked and would like an explanation, I simply thought that the map() would eliminate the need to a for loop.
Here is the code:

```
    class Welcome(object):
        MyHouse='Earth'
        def say(self, what):
            print(what, self.MyHouse)

    welcome = Welcome()

    Living = ['World', 'Planet', welcome.MyHouse]

    MyChoice = map(lambda choice : setattr(welcome, 'MyHouse', choice), Living)
    for i in MyChoice:
        getattr(welcome, 'say')('Hello')
```

That was a useless code , if i need a for loop why i am using lambda and map.